# Redundant storage using CRC

Tags: crc, redundancy, error-detection

Lets say I have a some 32 bit words in an embedded system storage. I want to protect that data using full redundant storage. This means to store each word twice and cross-checking the data word and its copy on each read access.

I was told that there is advantage in storing the copies in a different way. Especially it was said that it is better to store a 32 bit CRC checksum for each 32 bit data word instead of a 1:1 copy.

Normally CRCs help saving memory space while providing a certain degree of safety. However in the above situation this would no be the case. Instead it consumes CPU time for CRC computation.

So does the diverse redundancy described above make sense? In which way is it superior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard to imagine failure modes that would result in the same error in both 32-bit words, leading you to think that it was transferred correctly if you just sent a second copy. E.g., bit 3 is always stuck on.

On the other hand, it would be extremely unlikely that some failure mode would modify both the word and it's CRC in a way that would result in the correct CRC.

Comment: I see. For me it is a bit hard to find such failure modes. I can come up with data bus failures. What else do you have in mind?

Comment: Your memory failed and it is always delivering zeros.

Comment: By the way, for this application, you would be better off using far fewer than n redundant bits for n bits. A one-bit parity check will likely detect errors. A Hamming code of six bits for 32 will allow you to correct a one-bit error.

Comment: I edited "channel" to "memory" for your specific question. However "channel" is a general term for what the data is moving across, either in space (a wire) or in time (a memory).

Comment: Hm. Ok. I assumed that most common memory defects only affect a single bit or byte. But I guess to understand such a failure mode I would need to know more about internal memory structure. Something like defect output latches/drivers?

Comment: An entire chip up and died.